# Make list of not-nil entries

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

say I have a function like this:

```
(defn my-f [a & [b]]
   (if (nil? b)
      (my-other-f a)
      (my-other-f a b)))
```

This of course is a simplification. It's a wrapper function for another function - and in reality a is processed inside this function.
If the optional argument b is not passed to my-f, it should also not be passed to my-other-f.

I was thinking of another way to achieve this:

```
(defn my-f [a & [b]]
   (apply my-other-f (make-list-of-not-nil-entries a b)))
```

Is there maybe a built-in function doing this job?

---

**Example**

Sometimes, being too abstract is confusing, so I'm providing the real case here. The following ClojureScript code works, it's purpose is obviously to try different browser-specific options in order to get a "webgl" context from an HTML canvas element.

```
(defn create-ctx [canvas & [options]]
  (some (if options
          #(.getContext canvas % (clj->js options))
          #(.getContext canvas %))
        ["webgl" "experimental-webgl" "webkit-3d" "moz-webgl"]))
```

The given Canvas element's method getContext awaits actually one argument, and another one which is optional. The above wrapper functions has the same arity.

I just wanted to see, if there is a quick way to avoid the explicit switch for the 1 and the 2 arity function call.

Comment: is it an option to use different arities for `my-f` ? `(defn my-f ([a] (my-other-f a)) ([a b] (my-other-f a b)))`. That really looks like a problem of design. For example if you have 3 args fn: `(defn my-f [a b c])` with optional `b` and `c`, and `b == nil`, your approach with removing nils would pass `c` in place of `b`.. `(my-f 1 nil 100)`..

Answer (score 12):

I would argue that your first solution is much more readable and explicit about its intention.  It will also have much better performance than the one with `apply`.

If you still want to go with `apply`, the shortest solution using `clojure.core` would be:

```
(remove nil? [a b])
```

Or

```
(keep identity [a b])
```

Or

```
(filter some? [a b])
```

I am not aware of any built in function which takes varargs and returns a seq of only non nil elements. You could create one:

```
(defn non-nils [& args] 
  (remove nil? args)
```

Or use [`ignoring-nils`](https://github.com/amalloy/useful/blob/develop/src/flatland/useful/fn.clj#L108) from `flatland.useful.fn`.